# Integrand discontinuity of surface integral of electric field of dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, polarization, dipole

I am reading an article [here](https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/EM-913/section4-Electrostatics.pdf) on dielectrics

Equation $(4.10)$ is:

$$\Phi(\mathbf{r})=\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_{V} \dfrac{d^3r'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} [\rho (\mathbf{r'})\ -\nabla'.\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r'})]
+\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\oint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r'}).\mathbf{n}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}da$$

Since $\Phi(\mathbf{r})$ is potential, we can calculate the electric field by the formula $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=-\nabla\Phi(\mathbf{r})$

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=-\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_{V} \dfrac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})d^3r'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3} [\rho (\mathbf{r'})\ -\nabla'.\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r'})]
-\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\oint_S \dfrac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})\ \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r'}).\mathbf{n}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3}da$$

The volume integral in $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ has an integrand discontinuity when $\mathbf{r}$ lies in $V$. However this discontinuity is removable by switching to spherical coordinate system. Similarly the surface integral in $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$  has an integrand discontinuity when $\mathbf{r}$ lies in $S$. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the singularity, one usually uses an exclusion volume like
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \oint_{S,|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|>\delta} \dfrac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})\ [\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r'})\cdot\mathbf{n}]}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3}da$$
I have not derived that this is the correct extension of the surface integral (will require more accurate consideration of the interchange of $\nabla$ and the integral), but it gives the correct change of the normal component of the field, when passing through $S$.